# I am trying to go back to the previous page on click of a button in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: true}
    this.goBack = this.goBack.bind(this);
  }

  goBack() {
    this.props.history.goBack();
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <div className="App-header">
           <button onClick={this.goBack}>Go Back</button>
          </div>
          <Route path="/" exact render={() => <Home value={this.state.value}/>}/>
          <Route path="/details/:id" component={DetailView}/>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is code. On click of Back button i want to take me to the previous age. But this goBack() is not working for me. Probably I am making some mistake in using it.I tried couple of ways from guthub and stackover flow but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

can you try adding withRouter

```
import {..., withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
```

then change export to

```
export default wihRouter(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

`App` component does not receive `history` as prop because the `Router` is rendered inside it, instead you can create a wrapper component that is in the `route` to use `this.props.history`.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Content} />
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

For the content component:

```
class Content extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: true}
    this.goBack = this.goBack.bind(this);
  }

  goBack() {
    this.props.history.goBack();
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
         <button onClick={this.goBack}>Go Back</button>
        </div>
        <Route path="/" exact render={() => <Home value={this.state.value}/>}/>
        <Route path="/details/:id" component={DetailView}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, `Content` component is in the route and can receive the `history` prop.

---

Another way you can handle this is to simply render the `Content` component in `App` with `<Content />` and then use `withRouter` HOC on `Content`.

[withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter)

PS: You cannot apply `withRouter` to `App` component because technically `App` is outside the `Router`